# Reasons to downvote

Tags: discussion, downvotes, voting

I recently came across a poor question, one where the OP put in minimal effort to find the answers. Someone then came along and answered the question, with a simple and correct answer; however, they received a number of downvotes. One person specifically commented that they downvoted because the question was poor, and they didn't want to encourage users to answer poor questions.

My question is: When should something be downvoted?

I was under the impression that you downvote when the answer is incorrect, or not helpful, not because someone thinks the OP was poor.

Comment: Well, the user commented why he regards any answer to such a question as unhelpful (he might concede there are exceptionally stellar answers able to revert it, though xtremely rarely). What more shall we say?

Comment: So I leave a comment why I'm downvoting and then I'm summoned on meta to explain my explanation of my downvote?

Comment: So you came across [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29579096/string-to-char-array-with-seperators/29579128#comment47306832_29579128) poor question and you didn't leave a close vote? Why not?

Comment: @rene: Because I came too late. Left a delete-vote instead.

Answer (score 1):

I am very much torn here.

On one hand I am behind downvoting answers which are on "really" poor questions, because the question simply does not deserve an answer. It shows questioners that they will get an answer regardless of the quality of their question.

I have even seen questioners on really really bad questions tell me to stfu, and explain that I am among only a few people who think such questions are not welcomed.
They don' engage in comments, because they know someone will come along with an answer for them.
*Then* they start with comments, under the answer asking for more and more from the poor answerer, or telling them why it doesn't work and to update their answer.

Or worse, I have seen plenty "If you can show code which also does XYZ I will accept your answer".
This makes me want to downvote the question a million times!!

**That said**

I also don't think it's fair to downvote answers based on the question. The answer is usually ok, and away from a poor question well deserves a few upvotes.

I still only vote based on single merit, that is vote on the question based on the question, and vote on the answer based on the answer.  I think that is the only fair way.

I tend not to upvote an answer which is to a bad question, regardless of the answer quality, simply because they have answered a bad question.
I often check back later, and for the most part, these questions are closed off later on.

---

All that said, voting is very much a personal thing, so vote however you want to - everyone else does!

If you genuinely care for others and the site, then just try to be wise and fair in your voting.

Comment: As an aside, if the answerer cared, he could edit the question to get it up to par. Which would also get him more and well-disposed attention to his answer, as it would then be on an open and upvoted question.

Comment: @Deduplicator Yes, also the answer might actually help towards salvaging the question, as it brings a new scope and direction to bring the question i line with.

Comment: In this case, there's no "new direction", or any way to edit the question to make it better. It's a simple work-order for elementary string-handling in Java.

Comment: I have received a few downvotes without the voter providing any reason.  This is extremely frustrating, because I don't know what I did wrong or how to fix it.  The whole point of having a voting system is to enforce norms and I prefer to follow norms, but how can I do that if I have no indication of what norms I'm violating?  I urge the mods to require an explanation when submitting downvotes.